# How do you achieve the same animation as the iOS 7 Reminders app with UIKit Dynamics?

Tags: ios, uikit, uikit-dynamics

I am trying to achieve the animation behavior that mirrors the Reminders app in iOS 7 using UIKit Dynamics.  However, I am struggling on how to achieve this effect.  I have attempted to use UIAttachmentBehavior objects between current "card" and previous "card" and using a pan gesture to offset the cards with the y value of the drag behavior.  Yet I'm still unable to achieve the same effect.  Does anyone have any pointers on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution i have found - [TGLStackedViewController](https://github.com/gleue/TGLStackedViewController)

It provides same behaviour and uses the uidynamics library to attache views in a UICollectionView.